# Leaving a cell blank in excel, or display a different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I've tried to read the other posts and follow but I just can't wrap my head around this formula.

[image]

I would like `F9` to:

1. be blank if no data is entered in `D9`
2. if data is entered in `E9`, then `D9*E9`
3. if no data entered in `E9`, then `D9`

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(D9<>"",IF(E9<>"",E9,1)*D9,"")
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! I think i got too into my brain and started using ISBLANK and OR. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @meow_katz please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple formula here:

`=IF(ISBLANK(E9), D9, IF(ISBLANK(D9), "", D9*E9))`

This does however, leave `F9` with a `0` in it if neither field has any data.

To fix that you can add an `AND` check at the front, to check if either cell has data.

`=IF(AND(D9="", E9=""),"",IF(ISBLANK(E9), D9, IF(ISBLANK(D9), "", D9*E9)))`

Comment: @meow_katz No problem! Make sure you accept an answer if it helps you. Do check out Scott's answer as well. It does the same thing, but is a bit more compact than mine.

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D9)), IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E9)), D9 * E9, D9), "")
```

This aligns with your written rules and (imho) is easier to follow than Scott's answer - specifically the `1*D9` bit if there is no value in E9 - and removes the unnecessary `AND(D9="", E9=""),` clause from Michael's answer.